# Is it possible to use JetBrains MPS, or part of it, inside another application as JIT Compiler/Translator?

Tags: dsl, mps

Does JetBrains MPS provide an JIT compiler which can be used inside other applications?
We have a legacy application with its on script language. Because this script language is very difficult to use to our customer, we would like to provide a new DSL to them.

So the question is: Can we use Jetbrains MPS to design our DSL and then use the MPS JITCompiler/Translator to transform it to Java or whatever after the user wrote his script in our Software?

Comment: "with its on"  --> "with its own"?  So you want to a) design a replacement DSL, and b) presumably translate the legacy DSL to the replacement DSL?

Comment: ok i meant "own".Yes, i want a replacement DSL, transform the old scripts to the new DSL and the user needs a on the fly execution of the new DSL.

Comment: You'd get the equivalent by just running your old DSL engine without having to write a translator.  Why is that a necessary step?

Comment: Well we completly exchange the apllication and probably the script engine below as well, so old scripts need to be transformed into new form. Sorry i forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean by JITCompiler/Translator, to take your DSL generate Java from it and then run that compiled java code, yes that is possible. But it would be an extra transformation step like: write code -> generate/compile -> run (the resulting jar).

If you mean interpreting the model without doing a transformation step first then the answer is, not out of the box. We have build a interpreter framework for MPS and build two interpreters with it so far. One for Java and one for C. Though the focus is not on performance there. We use it for small calculations in formulas or REPL like things. It is currently work in progress but work quite nice. You can look [here](http://mbeddr.com/platform.html) for Interpreter and find some more information and where to look. As a midterm project we might want to integrate this interpreter definition with the [Graal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graal_(compiler)) compiler which would then be much more a JITCompiler then just a interpreter.

Comment: Thanks Kolja, the interpreter sounds promising. We would need something like this. The users are mechanical engineers and has normaly no idea about programming, so we would like to provide him a DSL with mechanical engineering as a domain to write scripts for our gear system calculation tool. Old scripts need to be transformed to the new DSL and new scripts should be interpreted/transformed/compiled from inside our application (their shouldn be a need to the user to use another tool then ours), and if possible the user should be able to debug it. Would that be possible with JetBrains MPS?

Comment: Yes debugging with MPS in general is possible. We have successfully integrated gdb with MPS to debug generated C. Our implementation also allows debugging on the abstraction level of the DSL. Currently we are conducting some active research on being able to debug on *all* intermediate abstraction level, too. In the case you have a multi step transformation. The interpreter got some basic support for debugging lately but it's in an early stage.